# if statement or loop

Tags: if-statement, while-loop

I am  trying to figure out if I need to use if statement or loop in my code. If random2 equals random1 then I want the random2 to generate another random number. If second time around random2 is again equal to random1, I want the code to keep running until it generates a different number from random1. Some guidance would be much appreciated.

```
public void generate(View view) {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int random1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
        int random2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
```

Comment: The question makes little sense. You use `if` if you need to test something once, you use a loop if you want to repeat code over and over. They're not comparable.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep that in mind. I wasn't sure what the difference between the two was. I did lot of reading on the net and it was going over my head. Thank you

Comment: That should be one of the first things you learn when learning how to program. It should be explained in any textbook.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a loop. Create a new random number until they differ:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int random1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
int random2;
do {
  random2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
} while(random1 == random2);
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much. I am guessing if I used the above code to ensure the third random number did nor equal to the previous two, it will also work. I will play with it now. Once again my sincere thank you to all those who responded so quickly

Comment: @Learningmind: Yes, you just need another loop after the first, where you compare the third number to the two other.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a loop:

```
Random rng = new Random();

int r1 = rng.nextInt(10);
int r2;

do {
    r2 = rng.nextInt(10);
while (r1 == r2);
```